# iOS 7 UITableView extends beneath UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uirefreshcontrol

**Project Overview**

I have a `UITableViewController` as the root view controller of a `UINavigationController`. Its view is a `UITableView` using the `UITableViewStyleGrouped` style. The table view also has a `UIRefreshControl`. I am not using nib/xib files, everything is created programmatically.

**Problem**

The header for the first section in my table view goes under the navigation bar. The refresh control, however, is in the right place. Normally problems with this are caused by a translucent navigation bar, but mine is opaque already.

**Attempted Solutions**

`self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone`

This doesn't produce any changes.

`self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);`

This puts my table view in the right place, but causes the refresh control to be adjusted down as well. Not to mention that this is a dirty solution anyway.

Comment: Are you certain it's not just a... wait for it... optical delusion?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
[self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];
```

Comment: This actually made everything worse. It moved up another 200px or so and the refresh control seems to be gone entirely (probably completely hidden by the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a plain viewcontroller and add the tableview there at the desired position.
This is because in case of an uitableviewcontroller the whole tableview is the parentview . I hope you got my point.